# MVC Storing image on network drive

Tags: google-chrome, networking, path

I have a MVC application, in which I am trying to store a image on a network drive and retrieve the same. The application works fine on IE but fails on chrome, upon spending some good amount of time on net I found that this is because of security reasons i.e. Chorme and Firefox prevent retrieving resource from network path and some suggested I have come across was setting UNC path- but even that did not work.

Below are some file path I configured on web.config

```
<add key="ImageLocation" value="\\user-one\share\UploadImages\" />
```

UNC Path.

```
<add key="ImageLocation" value="file\\user-one\share\UploadImages\" />
```

I would appreciate if someone has come across this issue and have any alternate solution or suggestion to address this.

Regards,
HSR.

Comment: By "MVC" do you mean "ASP.NET MVC"?  In what specific way is this failing?  Show the code you're using and indicate how it's behaving differently depending on the browser.

Comment: Thanks David for your prompt response, well yes its ASP.NET MVC  the code is simple i.e. in Img tag I use the below               <img src="@Url.Content(ViewBag.EmployeeImage)" width="150" height="50" alt="" /> where ViewBag.EmployeeImage contain the network path along with employee imagefilename.

Comment: So it's successfully uploading and it fails when you try to display it in the `img` tag?  In what way does it fail?  What is the value of `ViewBag.EmployeeImage`?

Comment: Well ViewBag.EmployeeImage contains the networkpath and imagefile name i.e. \\user-one\share\UploadImages\empid.jpg, this perfectly works on IE browser but fails on chrome without any error just displaying blank image.

Comment: It's definitely not standard to use a locally-browseable resource on a web page (whether it's a local file or on a network path).  Generally the web server that's serving the page would also serve the file, or at least use some HTTP location for the file.  Relying on a non-web resource is uncommon, perhaps even undefined behavior, and it wouldn't surprise me if browsers behave differently in that regard.

Comment: David - by Http location do you mean I have to create a virtual directory for the share location of different machine. Can you please clarify.

Comment: By HTTP location I mean that an `img` tag's `src` would much more commonly be something like this: `http://someserver/somepath/somefile.png` and not something like this: `\\somelocalpath\somefile.png`.  In a web environment you generally can'y rely on clients having access to resources which aren't provided by the server or which require different rights or protocols than the server itself requires.

Comment: Thanks David I tried this and  it has worked. The concern is once I host it will be exposed to outside world.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37467/discussion-between-harry-and-david)